# Bold font is offsetting text in separate table cell

Tags: tables

I'm creating a table that emulates a 2 column proposal layout. The table has three columns:

```
\begin{tabular}{|left column|empty space between|right column|}
```

I have the text in the left column vertically aligned with the text in the right column UNTIL I make the text in the left column bold- then the text in the right column drops vertically by a centimetre or two. How can I keep the text vertically aligned without dropping? Here is what I'm working with:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,12pt,mysize]{Proposal}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{midpage}
 \setlength{\tabcolsep}{.1em}
  \begin{tabular}{|m{8.2cm}|m{1cm}|m{8.2cm}|}
   \hline
    {\Large\textbf {Jack Smith,}}\newline
    {\Large\textbf CEO}\newline  
    & & 
    Peter Parker,\newline
    Spiderman\newline \\
   \hline
    Lorum & & Ipsum \\
   \hline
  \end{tabular}
```

Comment: Could you post an image of what the current (undesired) output is? Also, where might one find your `Proposal` document class (not sure whether it's necessary).

Comment: BTW, `@{\hspace{1cm}}` can be used instead of the middle dummy column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please always post complete documents using available class and package files.

Not having your class i can't be sure I see what you are seeing but you are using `m` which is why text in one column will move so that its centre aligns with the centre of the first column. Also never use a font size command such as `\large` in a local `{}` group without including the end of paragraph otherwise the line spacing is all wrong. I just removed the unneeded group. the lines are very close to the text as `\tabcolsep` is so small but that appeared to be intentional so I left it.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,lscape}
\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
 \setlength{\tabcolsep}{.1em}
  \begin{tabular}{|m{8.2cm}|m{1cm}|m{8.2cm}|}
   \hline
    {\Large\textbf {Jack Smith,}}\newline
    {\Large\textbf CEO}\newline  
    & & 
    Peter Parker,\newline
    Spiderman\newline \\
   \hline
    Lorum & & Ipsum \\
   \hline
  \end{tabular}

\bigskip

  \begin{tabular}{|p{8.2cm}|p{1cm}|p{8.2cm}|}
   \hline
    \Large\bfseries \strut Jack Smith,\newline
     CEO\newline  
    & & 
    Peter Parker,\newline
    Spiderman\newline \\
   \hline
    Lorum & & Ipsum \\
   \hline
  \end{tabular}

\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```